# problem in passing Data ajaxly

Tags: 8, ajax

I want to do some tasks with ajax in drupal, in client side I passed data with

```
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '/rest/session/token',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (token, status, xhr) {
                        var postData = {}
                        postData= {'name': 'user','pass': 'pass'};
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "/mylogin",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: postData,
                            dataType: "json",
                            headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "X-CSRF-Token": token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

and  ccording [How to get $_POST parameters](http://How%20to%20get%20$_POST%20parameters) in my controller I try to catch posted data with

```
public function login(){
    //return new JsonResponse( \Drupal::request()->request->all()); // form param);
    return new JsonResponse( \Drupal::request()->request->get('name')); // form param);
}
```

I reutrn empty, ( JsonResponse work correctly, I test it with example data ).

what is the problem and why I can't get Posted data in my controller's method?

Comment: The request/query get methods get raw data I think, i.e. there's no special handling to convert an incoming json string to key/value pairs. So there won't be a `$_POST['name']`, just raw post data that contains a JSON string.

Comment: @Clive then what is solution for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're POSTing a JSON string, it won't be available as key/value pairs in Symfony's request object.

You could parse it yourself:

```
$json_string = \Drupal::request()->getContent();
$decoded = \Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json::decode($json_string);
$name = $decoded['name'];
```